# How to refresh a panel after data is loaded?

Tags: extjs, refresh, panel

I have a extjs panel rendered inside a div like this:

```
panel = new Ext.Panel({
            layout : 'fit',
            renderTo: 'my_div',
            monitorResize: true, // relay on browser resize
            height: 500,
            autoWidth: true,
            items : [
                centerPanel
            ],
            plain : true
        });
```

After the page has loaded the panel is empty, but when I resize the browser the contents appears by magic!

I think the data has not finished loading when the panel is rendered the first time.

How can I get the contents to show without resizing the browser?

Comment: looks like very similiar issue as mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302727/gridpanel-data-not-rendered-when-loaded-after-initalization

Comment: similar in a way my panel is also depending on several webservices (called from within centerPanel), but is it also displaying the content only after the browser has been resized?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you need to explicitly cause the panel to be rendered. After creating the panel, make the following call:

```
panel.doLayout();
```

Sencha documentation says "A call to this function is required after adding a new component to an already rendered container, or possibly after changing sizing/position properties of child components."

Comment: Hi tedder, Your answer is correct and it works in Firefox, Chrome or any other but it doesn't work in IE. Can you tell me how to solve it in IE.

Comment: I'm using cshtml codes and bind a renderer function in JS code. The renderer function will only fired at page load. I want to fire it manually from JS and doLayout does not help. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

Any reason why you're nesting a panel within a panel?  Seems like `centerPanel` could be directly rendered to your containing div.  Also, the issue is most likely how you have `centerPanel` configured, or how you're loading it, neither of which you're showing here.  You should not need to call `doLayout()` manually in this case, it's probably an issue with how your components are configured.

Comment: @RobertP. In a larger layout, yes, sometimes. But generally-speaking when someone is nesting a single panel directly inside another single panel with layout: fit that indicates a misunderstanding of Ext's container/layout strategy. I don't think you bothered to read the full context of the question before downvoting me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

bmoeskau is right, also my guess is you have an async server request that loads your data (store.load, ajax, etc) -you could call the layout after that store loads by regestering a callback function (see sencha docs)

Answer (score 0):

**tedder** suggestion helped me, but in itself did not solve a similar problem I had: adding one `Ext.draw.Component` I got a blank panel.
The curious part is, the panel looked white, *but* the DOM components were all there and I could inspect them using e.g. Chrome developer tools.

I got it working by using a workaround. I added those 2 instructions after the call to `this.add(component)`:

```
this.setVisible(false);
this.setVisible(true);
```

Hiding the panel and then making it visible again, in some obscure way, does the job.

Comment: I'm using cshtml codes and bind a renderer function in JS code. The renderer function will only fired at page load. I want to fire it manually from JS and changing visibility does not help. Do you have any idea ?