# GridPanel data not rendered when loaded after initalization

Tags: extjs

I am quite new to ExtJS so this may be silly question.

I have a custom Panel, extending Ext's Panel class, which does an AJAX call and should create and populate an inner GridPanel with data obtained (columns are dynamic, so I can't prepare the grid earlier). `webService`'s first parameter is a callback function called with data when AJAX call encapsulated in `webService` object succeeds.

By now, I'm trying to populate my `TablePortlet` with hardcoded data and it works well when `renderCallback` method is called directly from `constructor`, but doesn't work at all if called after AJAX request. I can trace in Firebug that in this case the method is still called, `context` is valid, `store` is filled with data, but nothing is rendered.

How should I populate the data properly? Is there maybe any `render` method that I'm missing?

```
TablePortlet = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {

    constructor: function(portletTitle, sourceId, webService)
    {
        var context = this;

        TablePortlet.superclass.constructor.call(this, {
            title: portletTitle,
            anchor: '100%',
            frame:  true,
            collapsible:    true,
            draggable:  true
        });

        var grid = null;

        function renderCallback(data)
        {
            if (grid != null)
                context.remove(grid);

            var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                autoDestroy: true,
                fields:[{name:"a"}, {name:"b"}, {name:"c"}, {name:'d'}],
            });
            store.loadData([['1','2','1','2'],['3','4','3','4']]);

            grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                store: store,
                colModel: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
                    {header: 'A', dataIndex:'a'},
                    {header: 'B', dataIndex:'b'},
                    {header: 'C', dataIndex: 'c'},
                    {header: 'D', dataIndex: 'd'},
                ]),
                width: '100%',
                autoHeight: true,
                view: new Ext.grid.GridView(),
                viewConfig: {
                    forceFit: true
                },
                layout: 'fit'
            });

            context.add(grid);
        }

        this.on('render', function() 
        {
            webService.GetTable(renderCallback, sourceId);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the solution is:

```
context.doLayout();
```

Thanks to this parallel question: [How to refresh a panel after data is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302307/how-to-refresh-a-panel-after-data-is-loaded)

Comment: Hi NOtherDev, Your answer is correct and it works in Firefox, Chrome or any other but it doesn't work in IE. Can you tell me how to solve it in IE.